# Confusion using fork() and wait(), also is this the most efficient way?

Tags: c, fork, wait

I am trying to create this

```
                   P0
                  /  \  
                 P1  P2
                    / | \
                   P3 P4 P5
```

Using `fork()`
This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main()
{
  printf("P0 PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
  int pid1, pid2, pid3, pid4, pid5;
  pid1 = fork();
  int status = 0;
  if(pid1 != 0){
    pid2 = fork();
    if(pid2 != 0){
      waitpid(pid2, &status, 0); //If father, wait for child P2
      printf("%d\n", status);
    }
    else{
      printf("P2 PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
      pid3 = fork();
      if(pid3 != 0){ //If father (P2 at this point)
        waitpid(pid3, &status, 0); //Wait for child (P3)
        pid4 = fork();
        if(pid4 != 0){
          waitpid(pid4, &status, 0);
          pid5 = fork();
          if(pid5 == 0){
            printf("P5 PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
          }
        }
        else{
          printf("P4 PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
        }
      }
      else{
        printf("P3 PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    printf("P1 PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My goal is to make the very first process wait, until my `P2` process does everything it needs, and then proceed.
This line `printf("%d\n", status);` is to see when the `P0`(parent) process continues, but it prints in different places each time. I am very confused. Am I doing this right?
Also, is this the most efficient way to create what is described above?
Thank you

**UPDATE**

I changed some things in my code (see comments) and I use `waitpid` now. I think this is correct. I wait for P2 to end and P2 waits for P3, P4 to end too.
[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7h0w.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) of `wait`, (emphasis mine)

> The wait() system call suspends execution of the calling process until **one of its children** terminates.

In your case, in each execution, the order in which the children of `P0` complete their execution could be different. Once *any one child* completes execution, `P0` stops waiting and resumes. Even then, the order in which `P0` executes its `printf()` statement as compared to any children still executing might still be different every execution. Hence, it appears in a different place each time.

If you want to wait for all children to complete execution, then you need to call `wait` as many times as the number of children. In your case, you could call `wait` on `P2` three times and on `P0` two times to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer. I will try that. Will using `waitpid` as @Dinos_12345 suggested, make for a better solution?

Comment: `waitpid` gives you more control, you can specify a particular process to wait for,etc. From the man page, you can see that `wait` is equivalent to `waitpid(-1, &status, 0)`. Which to use probably depends on what you are using it for.